# PHP str_replace CSV Content

Tags: php

I am getting the contents of a CSV file and displaying (it works).

```
if (($handle = fopen($url, 'r')) === false) {
    die('Error opening file');
}


$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',');
$complete = array();
while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',')) {
    $complete[] = array_combine($headers, $row);
}
fclose($handle);
```

However, in this CSV file there is a field that has contents for example like this:

```
"123456,123456,123456,123456"
```

I *think* my code isn't processing because of the double quotes, I think I need to convert to single quotes. If thats the case how would I integrate the following (I was thinking something like):

```
str_replace('"',"'", $url);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the other parameters for [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

By default the enclosure character is set to ", which means anything between quotes should be considered a single value. Replace that parameter with what you actually use as the enclosure character in the csv and it will work.

Something like (if your enclosure character is '):

```
while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',', "'")) {
```

Better than to read it wrong and try to fix it afterwards with str_replace.

Comment: hi,thanks for taking the time - it looks like it's working! is there a quick way to only include the header and the next row?